# Django accessing foreign key value from api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

According to the DRF documentation [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views), in the class-based views, we can send a value argument using a keyword `pk`. I am trying to pass 2 values to the **GET** function in the following code.

example:

```
class studentList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, pk2, format=None):
        student_detail = Student.objects.filter(last_name = pk, campus_id.name = pk2)
        serialized_student_detail = studentSerializer(student_detail, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_student_detail.data)
```

In the above, the `campus_id` is a foreign key relation to another model and hence it is returning me an error. How can we access the vlues of the foreign key here? In my serializer, i mentioned the depth to be 1 so that it fetches the values from the foreign key relationship. How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the double underscore to access a ForeignKey relationships attributes

```
student_detail = Student.objects.filter(last_name=pk, campus__name=pk2)
```